# Баг или можно исправить title right-border in FireFox?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, firefox

```html
<span title="Veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooonggg naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaammmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee">Hover me</span>
```

Смысл бага в чем, при длинном title когда наводишь на элемент **только в FF (FireFox v50.1.0 и ниже)** куда-то пропадает правый бордер у всплывающей подсказки, может кто сталкивался с подобным и знает как решить данный глюк.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это официальный баг в **Firefox**, который так и не исправили до сих пор.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=805039

Comment: Только это дубликат бага который закрыт, а вот сам баг https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=805039

Comment: @Shnur, спасибо, я, видимо, поспешил слегка. Исправлю

Answer (score 0):

при помощи css можно создать тултип

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <style>
    .tooltip {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    }

    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 120px;
        background-color: #555;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: 125%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -60px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 1s;
    }

    .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
    }

    .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    </style>
    <body style="text-align:center;">

    <h2>Tooltip</h2>
    <p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

    <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
      <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Это не решение проблемы. Еще и кучу элементов прописывать.

Comment: эту проблему решить нельзя, проблема с бравзером/ это давно известно

Comment: Да, но и Ваше решение, не лучшее. )))

Answer (score -1):

ну поскольку это баг firefox как написали выше то я нашел способ как его исправить )

```js
document.getElementById("s").title = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\nbbbbbbbbbb";
```

```html
<span id="s">text</span>
```